# Deleting Subscriber using Automation based on condition

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation

My question is if receive a file where it has one field condition to delete the subscriber in the SFMC. The first step is to create to query the DE and import them in to one DE. Then Manually clear the data in DE. However, is there a way to delete the subscriber in DE using automation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing first, there is a SSJS function that deletes the row in the Data Extension. Here are the steps to reproduce the automation.

**OPTION 1**

**Step 1:** Create a DE **A** which has the same primary key as the original DE **B** you're willing to purge. Then a SQL query to inject the subscribers which have the delete flag from the original DE **B** to the new DE **A**.

**Step 2:** Now the new DE **A** has the subscribers which needs to be purged, and can use this DE as a lookup reference to delete the subscribers in the original DE **B**.

**Step 3:** Write a Server Side JavaScript (SSJS) function to first **[Lookup](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/platform_server_side_javascript_functions/interact_with_data_extensions_using_the_function_object/lookup/)** on the reference DE **A** and then the **[DeleteData](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/platform_server_side_javascript_functions/interact_with_data_extensions_using_the_function_object/deletedata/)**. These both functions will be wrapped with a `for` loop within a Script Activity which will run after `SQL` query in your automation.

> Flow: SQL > Script (SSJS)

**OPTION 2**

Follow **Step 1** and **Step 2** for this option. On **Step 3** you can also include an email activity if you wish to run the automation using the AMPscript function. The **[DeleteDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/deletede.htm)** function can be used within an email and hence can be used to notify users on how many records were purged.

> Flow: SQL > Email (AMPscript)